# Pass display name to SIP client

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, linphone, twilio-twiml

My server responds with this [TwiML](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml) snippet when receiving an inbound call.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
    <Dial>
        <Sip>sip:jack@example.com</Sip>
    </Dial>
</Response>
```

This works but Jack's SIP client ([linphone](https://www.linphone.org/)) shows the phone number of the caller. Our server knows the name of the caller (matching phone numbers) so I could add that to the TwiML response so the SIP  client could show the name of the client instead of/next to the phone number.

I understand you can add [custom headers](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/sip?code-sample=code-custom-headers-with-sip-9&code-sdk-version=5.x) to the `<Sip>` element but I have no idea what or if linphone picks up on one of these fields. Something in the style of:

```
--- 8< snip ---
<Sip>sip:jack@example.com?x-displayname=JohnDoe</Sip>
--- 8< snip ---
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Twilio developer evangelist here. I'd love to help, but I think you have the Twilio side of this down and I don't know enough about Linphone to suggest anything. Good luck finding the answer though.

Comment: Maybe,  Reason: SIP ;cause=200 ;text="Call completed elsewhere"  from  [linphone](https://wiki.linphone.org/xwiki/wiki/public/view/Lib/Features/Reason%20Header%20support/)